# Does the C++ standard require its own iterators to be nothrow move/copy constructable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In MSVC the type trait std::is_nothrow_move_constructible is true for iterators (at least for map, set & vector) in release build, but not in debug build.

Comment: Try to tell about it more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the standard library's iterator categories have any particular requirements of that nature. All iterators are required to be CopyConstructible, but no iterators have a requirement on non-throwing move constructible.